# Python - pixels to images

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in Python that takes an image and replaces the pixels with images, based off of the pixels lightness value. Figured I'd start with following a tutorial on converting images to ASCII art, then I can replace the ASCII characters with images. Here's what this attempt looks like:

https://pastebin.com/VNFWd9xN

It's a bit quick and dirty, just to see if I can make it work, but I think you'll get the idea.

So, a couple of issues I ran into.

The first and biggest one, i get a "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, JpegImageFile found". I get that the program expects a string and gets an image instead. But, how do I solve that?

Lastly, more of a parenthesis really, but I was playing around with the save function and could not get it so save "ascii_image" to jpg.

Anyhow, would really appreciate some guidance here.

Thank you.

```
    import PIL.Image
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open("image1.jpg")
img2 = Image.open("image2.jpg")
img3 = Image.open("image3.jpg")
img4 = Image.open("image4.jpg")
img5 = Image.open("image5.jpg")
img6 = Image.open("image6.jpg")
img7 = Image.open("image7.jpg")
img8 = Image.open("image8.jpg")
img9 = Image.open("image9.jpg")
img10 = Image.open("image10.jpg")
img11 = Image.open("image11.jpg")
img12 = Image.open("image12.jpg")

# ascii characters used to build the output text
#ASCII_CHARS = ["@", "#", "S", "%", "?", "*", "+", ";", ":", ",", "."]
ASCII_CHARS = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img8, img9, img10, img11, img12]


# resize image according to a new width
def resize_image(image, new_width=80):
    width, height = image.size
    ratio = height/width
    new_height = int(new_width * ratio)
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    return(resized_image)

# convert each pixel to greyscale
def grayify(image):
    grayscale_image = image.convert("L")
    return(grayscale_image)

# convert pixels to a string of ASCII characters
def pixels_to_ascii(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    characters = "".join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel//25] for pixel in pixels])
    return(characters)

def main(new_width=80):
    # attempt to open image from user-input
    path = input("Enter path to image:\n")
    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open(path)
    except:
        print(path, " is not a valid pathname to an image")
        return

    # convert image to ASCII    

    new_image_data = pixels_to_ascii(grayify(resize_image(image)))

    # format
    pixel_count = len(new_image_data)
    ascii_image = "\n".join([new_image_data[index:(index+new_width)] for index in range(0, pixel_count, new_width)])

    # print result
    print(ascii_image)

    # save
    #with Image.open("ascii_image.jpg") as f:
    #   f.write(ascii_image)
    

main()
```

Comment: You're trying to join images with `"".join()` and `"\n".join()`?? I'm sorry, there's no way that could work. `"\n".join` for example interpolates newlines between the text strings passed to it, which is completely unrelated to images. Before you worry about other things, I think you first need to find out how to combine your images, then attempt to do so. You might want to create an output image and then paste the input images into it in the proper locations.

Comment: Makes sense. Treating images as strings is a bad idea. 

I'm not sure how to do this - in fact very little idea how to construct it in Python - but let me try and break it down a little bit, and see if it's a sensible approach?

Load source image
Resize
Convert to greyscale

Make an array with the pixel values from the converted image

Create a blank canvas with the dimension of the converted source image.

For each value in array between 0-10 load an image, and for each value between 11-20... into that position in blank canvas

Save blank canvas to file.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ps. Sorry for the formatting. I'm unfamiliar with how this site works.